# have you been refused , is it correct?

Tags: present-perfect

If my friend have passed an exam and now she is receiving the results, should I say:

Have you been refused somewhere?

Indeed, before the exam she had ranked schools for the next year. And now with the results, we will now if she has been refused somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean to ask if she has failed a subject?

Comment: Sorry, I have added more context.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by "she had ranked schools" and "if she has been refused somewhere".  Do you mean that she made a list of schools that she wanted to go to, and you are asking if any of these schools have refused to admit her?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence makes no sense in English given the admittedly murky context provided.

If you are unsure whether your friend has received the results of the exam, you might ask questions like

> How did you do on your exam?

or

> Have you received the results of your exam yet?

If you are sure that she knows the results, you would ask things like

> How did you do on your exam?

or

> You aced that exam, didn’t you?

or

> You didn’t fail that exam, did you?

Now it is quite possible to imagine a context in which someone was granted or denied **something** based on the results of an exam

> Were you denied admission to Harvard [because of the results of the SAT exam]?

In that case, “refused” is an acceptable synonym for “denied.” But notice that what is being refused is a privilege rather than a place. The phrase “refused somewhere” is just not idiomatic.

Comment: I have completed the context. About your last sentence "were you denied[...]", why I cannot use the present perfect?

Comment: You can use the present perfect, but that was not your question.

Comment: The fundamental point is that places are inanimate concepts that do not have the capacity to refuse anything. Moreover, “refuse” requires an object, explicit or implicit. You cannot refuse a place. It is a meaningless phrase. You could legitimately say “refused [admission] **by** Harvard” although the omission of “admission” is unnatural except in a specific context.  The additional omission of “by” reduces the sentence to unintelligibility. In short, using “refuse” this way is not even close to idiomatic English.